# Parsing Path type

Tags: dhall

I was trying to make an instance for the `Path` type. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/path

If I use the generic.

```
instance FromDhall (Path Rel Dir)
```

This doesn't do any normalisation of directories. I initially assumed this would piggyback off the defined FromJSON instances which in turn call `parseRelDir` etc, but that's not the case, and when I tried to implement this manually I realised I'm quite in over my head. What's the way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The derived instance will use the shape of the `Path` datatype.  Even though the `Path` constructor is not exposed it still provides a `Generic` instance, which is enough for the `FromDhall` instance to derive something.

In this case, since `Path` is internally defined as:

```
newtype Path b t = Path FilePath
```

… then the derived `FromDhall` instance will expect a Dhall value of something like this type:

```
{ _1 : Text }
```

… which is the derived Dhall type for a data type with 1 anonymous field that is a `String`/`FilePath`.

This is probably not what you wanted (as you noted), so if you want different behavior you will need to implement the `FromDhall` instance yourself.

So what you will probably want to write is something like:

```
instance FromDhall (Path Rel Dir) where
    -- Our `Decoder` will be similar to the `filePathDecoder`,
    -- except with a different `extract` function
    autoWith options =
        Decoder
            { extract = extractPath
            , expected = expectedPath
            }
      where
        filePathDecoder :: Decoder FilePath
        filePathDecoder = autoWith options

        -- To extract a `Path`, first extract a `FilePath`
        -- and attempt to parse it into a `Path`
        extractPath expression =
          case extract filePathDecoder expression of
              Success filepath ->
                  case Path.parseRelDir filePath of
                      Left exception ->
                          Dhall.extractError (Text.pack (show exception))
                      Right path ->
                          Success path
              Failure e -> Failure e

        -- The expected Dhall type for a `Path` is the same
        -- as for a `FilePath`
        expectedPath = expected filePathDecoder
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive example. How is it automagically absorbing the MonadThrow constraint to an Either?

Comment: @locallycompact: There is an `instance (e ~ SomeException) => MonadThrow (Either e)` in the `exceptions` package